# Как добавить клас active к текущей ссылке после перехода по ней, а в предыдущей забрать

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Я использую ruby on rails, есть шаблон для меню, на каждую страницу.
На классе active висить css чтоб стилизовать текущую ccылку.
Вопрос: как добавить класс "active" после клика к ccылке, а в предыдущей забрать?

```
<div class="l-mnu">
    <ul>
        <li class="l-cat active"><%= link_to "Нове", root_path %></li>
        <li class="l-cat"><%= link_to "Чоловіче", mens_path %></li>
        <li class="l-cat"><%= link_to "Жіноче", womens_path %></li>
        <li class="l-cat"><%= link_to "Аксесуари", accessories_path %></li>
        <li class="l-cat"><%= link_to "Новини", news_path %></li>
        <li class="l-cat"><%= link_to "Контакти", contact_path %></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.l-mnu ul li a').click(function(){
     if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
      return false;
    }
   $('.l-mnu ul li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: ссылки на самом деле такие `<a href="#">`? Или при клике происходит редирект?

Comment: Ну при клике на ссылку происходить переход на другую страницу. Проблема в том,что после перехода  клас "active" не сохраняеться на текущей ccылке. А надо получаеться сначала сделать переход а после добавить класс "active"/

Comment: _переход на другую страницу_ - это редирект? либо используется какой-нибудь history api, или просто хэш(текст после # в url) меняется?

Comment: вот оригинал кода 
<li class="l-cat active"><a href="index.html">Нове</a></li>
<li class="l-cat"><a href="mens.html">Чоловіче</a></li>

Comment: И код, который в вопросе - в каждый из этих файлов подключается?

Comment: я использую ruby on rails, 
<li class="l-cat active"><%= link_to "Нове", root_path %></li>
<li class="l-cat"><%= link_to "Чоловіче", mens_path %>

есть шаблон, тоисть ето получаеться меню которое подключаеться к разным страницам, если ето было б несколько html-файлов то я б попросту в каждому прописал "active".

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас была ошибка синтаксиса.
Сам код работающий.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.l-mnu ul li a').click(function(){
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
        return false;
    }
    $('.l-mnu ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>.active { background: #FF0 }</style>
<div class="l-mnu">
 <ul>
   <li class="l-cat active"><a href="#">New</a></li>
   <li class="l-cat"><a href="#">Mens</a>
   <li class="l-cat"><a href="#">Womens</a>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Код то работающий, но при клике добаляеться класс "active" но после клика происходит переход на другю страницу і класс соответсвенно пропадает. Получаеться что надо сделать сналачала переход а после перехода по ссылке добавить класс "active" к текущей ссылке. Как-то так

Comment: @PetroZendran эти табы реализованы на js, а это значит, что неактивные табы уже должны быть подготовлены к показу, из просто нужно переключить. Если же у вас табы не готовы, то js вам тут не поможет.

Comment: @mix, поможет, если проверять текущий урл и искать его в href у пунктов меню

Comment: @Grundy если поможет, то продемонстрируйте нам это, чтобы у автора отпали все вопросы.

Comment: @mix, судя по комментарию под вопросом - проще все-таки выставлять на сервере

Comment: @Grundy судz по комментариям под вопросом, как раз становится ясно, что автор хочет сделать табы не js, как понятно из самого вопроса, а статичными страницами. Из этого вывод, что js тут не причем и ему он не поможет.